# How to find userAgent of Google API callers?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, useragent

I have a Google Cloud project that has YouTube API active through some known API Key. I am trying to find out the user agents of its callers in order to break them down by type (this is an old project and may have multiple and some legacy callers I wish to discover)

How do I get that information?
Thanks!